# Black square when trying to open Steam

Tags: steam

I am on Windows 7 and I updated Steam two days ago and it worked fine until today.
Now when I click on it a dialog box shows up saying "Verifying Steam Installation" for about 3 seconds then a black box appears for about 5-10 seconds then nothing. It doesn't show up in Task Manager.

I tried removing the ClientRegistry.blob file and restarting like I saw on some forums. Now it does the same thing except there is a third black box which is larger that doesn't go away.

Any suggestions on what I should do or where else I can try looking?

Comment: Is the black box the size of the login window? Because that happens under Linux for me.

Comment: @Sentry I think so (it's been a while since I've had to log on)

Answer (score 2):

I removed all of the files except for Steam.exe and the SteamApps folder.
Once I started steam again it rebuilt the files and started up normally.

Hope this helps someone else.